# Case-insensitive partial keyword search on 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, case-insensitive, partial-matches

I have multi dimension arrays in which I want to look for some particular words
this is how my array looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sch_name] => Montfort School Roorkee
            [sch_degree] => High School
            [sch_field] => Commerce
            [sch_grade] => A+
            [sch_from_year] => 2007
            [sch_to_year] => 2015
            [sch_desc] => Montfort School was very nice
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sch_name] => City Public
            [sch_degree] => 12
            [sch_field] => Commerce
            [sch_grade] => 12
            [sch_from_year] => 2007
            [sch_to_year] => 2015
            [sch_desc] => Great School
        )

)
```

Now suppose i want to find 'montfort' word in this multi dimensional array

So i tried using this function

```
function searchForWord($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['sch_name'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
echo $id = searchForWord('montfort', $p);
```

it resulted in nothing but when I wrote 'Montfort School Roorkee' result was found, why these word are so sensitive is there any other way to get values

Can't I use something like we do in a MySQL query `LIKE '%keyword'`?

Comment: Note that this is nothing to do with arrays: it's an issue with your understanding of basic operators like `===`

Comment: `if ($val['sch_name'] === $id)` is searching for an exact match; your `$id` string must exactly match the `$val['sch_name']` string; but the value in `$id` is only part of the string that you want to match, so you need to check for a partial match. `if (stripos($val['sch_name']), $id !== false) {`. Note also that `strpos()` is case-sensitive; `stripos()` is case-insensitive

Comment: @MarkBaker if (stripos($val['sch_name']), $id !== false) { } is giving syntax error

Comment: OK, so I typed too quickly: `if (stripos($val['sch_name'], $id) !== false) {`

Comment: @MarkBaker please write it as answer so i can up vote and mark it as an answer

Comment: @MarkBaker how can i get all keys where montfort word will be found?

Comment: `$results = array_filter($myArray, function($value) { return stripos($value['sch_name'], $id) !== false; });` will return all rows that contain `$id` in the `sch_name' element, and assign that to $result. If you only want the keys, then run `array_key()` on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cols = array_column($your_array,'sch_name');
$keys = [];
foreach ($cols as $k=>$v) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($cols[$k]),strtolower('Mont'))!==false) {
        $keys[]=$k;               
    }
}
print_r($keys);
```

replace $your_array with your array.

it's case insensitive and will match anything partial. You could make it a function like so:

```
function SearchArrayForKeys($array,$column_name,$search) {
    if (!$array||!is_array($array)) {
        return [];
    }
    $cols = array_column($array,$column_name);
    if (!$cols){
        return [];
    }
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($cols as $k=>$v) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($cols[$k]),strtolower($search))!==false) {
            $keys[]=$k;               
        }
    }        
    return $keys;
}
```

usage:

```
$keys = SearchArrayForKeys($your_array,'sch_name','Mont');
```

Comment: $keys results in empty array

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are actually trying a complete string match `if ($val['sch_name'] === $id)` which wouldn't return true unless the input search pattern is the whole string.

To find partial strings from a string use `strpos(<string>,<pattern>)`.

For example:

```
<?php
   $needle='Montfort';
   $haystack='Montfort School was very nice';

   if(strpos($haystack,$needle)!==false){
     print("Found");
   }
   else{
     print("Not Found");
   }
?>
```

Also if you want a case insensitive comparison use `strtolower` on both strings which you use in the `strpos` match.

Eg : `if(strpos(strtolower($haystack),strtolower($needle))!==false)`